# Which NHS degrees still receive funding

Tags: university, united-kingdom, degree

I've read from the NHS website that radiologists will stop receiving full funding from the UK government. I'm wondering if any other NHS related degrees have also had funding stopped for them, and which continue to receive funding

Comment: This seems like a question that could be readily answered with the help of Google.

Comment: I agree with @Ian_Fin. For this sort of question, ASE is not suitable. Just google it out.